# Error message: "A sharepoint server is not installed..."

Tags: development, visual-studio

Im trying to develop a Visual Web Part using Visual Studio 2010 RC. I have not installed SharePoint 2010 locally on my developer box, but I have installed it on my Windows 2008 Server VPC.

When I try to create a new project I get this message:

*A SharePoint server is not installed on this computer. A SharePoint server must be installed to work with SharePoint projects.*

Is it so that I have to install SharePoint server on my developer box, or is there any workaraounds for this. If I have to, can I install SharePoint Foundation 2010 or the whole package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you will need to be running SharePoint on your local box.

You **could**, technically develop a web part on your developer machine by making a reference to the appropriate dlls.  However you will not be able to use the native Visual Studio 2010 SharePoint integration as this relies on the ability to deploy and provision your solutions to a local SharePoint farm for the F5 debugging process.

There are probably work arounds which will **significantly** reduce the UX of Visual Studio for SharePoint development.

You can install SPF if you only intend to use components from it but you need the additional elements to support SPS if your working with that product.

Comment: Thank you! As I was afraid of, I have to install the server on my own box. Better start working :D

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. Exported the following hive from SP2010 server machine and imported it on my windows 7 development machine, and it works,projects get created.

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Shared Tools\Web Server Extensions\14.0

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepoint2010programming/thread/cda807f6-4edf-4efc-8e9b-4d446356c8ae

Regards,
Shweta

Answer (score 1):

Check this post in my blog: [Remotely working and debugging SharePoint 2010 solutions](http://www.raminassar.com/blog/2011/11/24/remotly-working-and-debugging-sharepoint-2010-solutions/).

Comment: While  this may theoretically answer (or be relevant to) the question, we prefer inclusion of the  essential parts of the answer here, and to provide the link for  reference.

Comment: Also, you can include the full link... there isn't a 140 character limit. ;)

Comment: @Kit Good point. I've fixed this.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you need SharePoint on the same box to develop these. SharePoint Foundation will do. I would not recommend any workarounds.