# Sharepoint not Installed

Tags: development, visual-studio

Hello I'm trying to create a sharepoint 2010 project.  I have Sharepoint as well as Visual studio 2012 installed on a VM, but when i go to create a new sharepoint project it tells me "Sharepoint not installed" I'm guessing I have to configure something to see the sharepoint installation in the system and I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

- Install the sdk: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=12323
- Install SharePoint on the development box.

I would create a dev environment - otherwise you have to copy the solution to test deploy it and debugging is a pain.

Comment: I comprehend it as he has got SharePoint installed on his dev mashine

Comment: Yepp, I misread the question, thanks! I think bullet 1 still applies even though it should work from start depending on your OS in the VM.

Comment: Yes probably, it could also be some configuration error in the sharepoint installation

Comment: I do have sharepoint installed on the same machine as visual studio.

Comment: Also I just tried installing the SDK, but nothing changing I'm still having the issue.

Comment: Have you read this: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/15898/how-to-fix-a-sharepoint-server-is-not-installed-on-this-computer