# Developing in Windows 8 without Sharepoint installed

Tags: 2010, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to install a development environment for Sharepoint (**update:** 2010) in a Windows 8 box without installing Sharepoint localy.

I managed to have VS (2012 by the way) creating SP projects - I followed these links [1](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/en/sharepointdevelopmentprevious/thread/cda807f6-4edf-4efc-8e9b-4d446356c8ae) [2](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/2785/error-message-a-sharepoint-server-is-not-installed)

But now I have another problem I cant seem to fix. I can build an existing project with VisualWebParts, but if I try to create a new one I get this error : Cannot find custom tool 'SharePointWebPartCodeGenerator' on this system

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: which sharepoint is it

Comment: sp2010, updated post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that using Visual Studio 2010 it works.

After the steps defined in the two links I gave in the question, just instaling VS 2010 worked.

Hope this helps some one else. And if somebody finds a way to do this using VS2012 I'll change the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Presuming you are trying to develop for SharePoint 2013 as remote development isn't supported by earlier version of SharePoint as said in this MSDN documentation, If you follow this guide it says you need to install sharepoint development tools on your machine, I wonder if you installed them yet.

This [article on MSDN goes through remote development in SharePoint 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj220047.aspx). For earlier version I tried Visual Studio remote debugger which works well as well and more information about it can be found by following this [Link (How to setup remote debugging.)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/bt727f1t.aspx)

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks foy your reply, but I'm still using SP2010.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have SharePoint 2010 installed on the machine you wish to do development on.  However, installing SharePoint 2010 on Windows 8 is unsupported (and may or may not be supported when SharePoint 2010 SP2 is released).

SharePoint 2013 remote development is only good for developing "Apps", traditional solutions still must be developed locally.

I'd suggest using a virtual machine (Hyper-V or VMware Workstation/Player) with Server 2008 R2, SharePoint 2010, and Visual Studio installed in it.

Comment: Yes I understant that this is the only "supported" way, but still I'm stuborn. I've manage to build a SP project in this config, the only thing I cant do is create new visual web parts

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd want to take an unsupported approach to development.

Comment: @RicardoGomes developing something isn't a problem or big deal, problem is when you will test it and debug it, you can have needed dlls and you can build a project but how you gonna debug it ?

Comment: @TimeToShine thank you for your reply, and indeed that is a problem, but I have a Testing Server in which to deploy and debug, and also a Build Definition (using TFS Build Server) that does the deployment, so all I need is to actually code and build in Windows 8. I actually "solved" part of the problem, I can build in windows 8 using VS2010, but not in VS2012.