# Using sharepoint 2010 on another server in VS?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, visual-web-part, visual-studio-2012

How can I use sharepoint 2010 that is on another server in VS?
When I try to create a new project for creating visual web part, A message "Sharepoint not installed on this client" is showed.

Answer (score 2):

You can develop VS projects **ONLY** on the same server where SharePoint is installed.

By the way, if you're using SharePoint 2013, you can develop APPS on a remote Server but that's another story.

Answer (score 0):

Same question [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/2785/error-message-a-sharepoint-server-is-not-installed) with some suggestions for a workaround. A workaround is not recommended, though.

By the way, I had the same problem, and installed SharePoint Foundation 2010. It does not have all the options like a "regular" SharePoint, but it is free, runs fast and matches the requirements to run a decent test. The installation is described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869%28office.14%29.aspx). Just make sure you follow every step from the article. There is also a great tutorial covered with screenshots [here](http://biblog.ptsgroup.de/sql-server/sharepoint-foundation-2010-mit-sql-server-2008-r2-express-installationsanleitung-schritt-fur-schritt/). It`s in German, but I think you can manage to get the essence out of it.